# Eroor in command django-admin manage.py make migrations

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

[this is the entire output of this command then the output is looked like this.now as a beginner its very difficult for me to solve it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GccvD.png)

Comment: And that is the area where you should enter a description that explains the issue you're having

Comment: whether you have not mentioned your app in installed apps in settings.py or you did not set your paths in environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `manage.py` not `django-admin.py`.

In future, please ask proper questions on StackOverflow: you should explain the issue, copy and paste the actual *text* of the error (not a screenshot) into the question itself, and describe exactly what you tried to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

firstly the command should be:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

second are you using virtualenv? If so your virtualenv is not activated and that is causing this error. And if you're not, then you should see some tutorial on using django with virtualenv.
However, if you dont want to use virtualenv(highly unrecommended), you should probably export the DJANGO_SETTINGS_PATH variable in your terminal thus:

```
$ export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='project_name.settings'
```